# error: Invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I got the following problem, does anyone have a good idea?

```
class Vector_2d;

namespace Utils {

class Align_vector : public Vector_2d {
protected:
    bool check_range(int x, int y);

public:
    enum alignment {left, right, up, down};

    Align_vector(Alignment alignment);
    void set_alignment(Alignment alignment);
    Alignment get_alignment();

};

}
```

the error is:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Vector_2d’

But how is there an error?

Comment: You can't use an incomplete type as a base class : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration

Comment: You're publicly inheriting from `Vector_2d` so you need access to the implementation so you need to `#include` the header where it's declared, the forward class declaration won't help you here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`class Vector_2d;` This only declares a class by that name exits.
To inherit from it, the full class definition needs to be available.

```
class Vector_2d {
  // Your code goes here
};

class Align_vector : public Vector_2d {
  // Other stuff
};
```

If you have separate header files for these classes, be sure to include it before defining the class that inherits.

```
#include <vector_2d.h>

namespace Utils {
    class Align_vector : public Vector_2d {
      // Other stuff
    };
}
```

To put it simply, when class `B` inherits from class `A`, objects of class `B` will have an `A` sub-object as part of their layout.
So you can't define the layout of `B`, which depends on `A`, if you don't have the full definition of `A`.

Comment: what do you mean exactlly?